# getting error in android NDK while using ndk-build

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

i am new in android ndk and i m making connection of java and c/c++ code and at last moment when i use ndk-build command then i got this error.

please help me to clear this problem.

I am working on ubuntu 12.04. and i got same error on both linux and windows and on windows i use using cygwin.

Error-

```
/home/saicomputer/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK:      WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in  ./AndroidManifest.xml
 Compile thumb : myjni <= native.c
 jni/native.c: In function 'Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_hello':  
jni/native.c:4:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:4:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:5:10: error: 'env' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native.c:5:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
jni/native.c: In function 'Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_add':
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:9:3: error: parameter name omitted
jni/native.c:10:9: error: 'value1' undeclared (first use in this function) 
jni/native.c:10:18: error: 'value2' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/myjni/native.o] Error 1
```

please help me out to overcome this problem.

thanks.